# How to get the dead letter queue for a given SQS queue using boto3?

Tags: boto3, amazon-sqs

Using boto3 resource, how can I get the DLQ for a particular SQS queue?

I thought it was `dead_letter_source_queues`, but the use case is reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would call [get_queue_attributes](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.get_queue_attributes) and check the `RedrivePolicy.deadLetterTargetArn` value in the response.